# Using Filezilla to upload files to remote server under a proxy server

Tags: proxy, ftp, sftp, filezilla

I am using Filezilla to upload files to my web server. I am under a proxy server of my college. I edited FTP proxy in Filezilla Settings. However, it shows the following error :-

```
Status: Selected port usually in use by a different protocol.
Status: Connecting to myServerIp:port...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "prashant@myServerIp" port
Error:  Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I set the value of host to `sftp://myServerIP` while connecting to the remote server.

Any help to by-pass my proxy server ?

Comment: Does your web server reside under the same network as your Filezilla client?

Comment: @Trey No the server is located somewhere else